# Initialization of an interface of Strings in Groovy

Tags: class, oop, groovy, interface

```
interface PRINT {
  def LN = '\n\n'
  def BREAK = '='*80
}
println PRINT.BREAK
```

I'm getting this error while trying to initialize `BREAK`:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: PRINT$1

There's an issue with  `'='*80`, what could be the reason and what would be a better approach for this?
It works without the multiplication.

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jeffbrown/ed0995b743d9556cb7e6e942f5b65a80 is what I am seeing.

Comment: Does `def BREAK = "${'='*80}"` behave any differently for you?